# pygame module not found (Windows 10, Spyder IDE version 4.1.3, Python 3.8)

Tags: python, pygame, spyder

So pygame is definitely on my computer, and I can call it through the Python terminal that was installed when I downloaded Python 3.8. However, I can't get Spyder to import the pygame module. When I do, it gives me this error message:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

Could someone please walk me through how I set up pygame so that Spyder can recognize the pygame module? Thanks!

Comment: What is the import statement you are using for pygame? And also how did you install it?

Comment: Can you show your python code? Here is a question on how to write a good question. To have a better experience in using Stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You've only installed pygame into a different python editor. If you want it to work on spyder, you should install it via the pip that belongs to spyder.